# Understanding presynaptic and postsynaptic inhibition

Tags: neuroscience, neuron

One way to classify neural inhibition is based on the inhibition being "presynaptic" or "postsynaptic".

As far as I understand, the two different types of inhibition refer to the following:

- **Presynaptic inhibition**: A neuron N1 is inhibited "indirectly" insofar as the *presynaptic excitatory neuron's* action on it are dampened. This is typically achieved by neurotransmitter's impact on the presynaptic excitatory neuron which inhibit Ca2+ channels, and consequently prohibit vesicle release of neurotransmitter's into the synaptic cleft - hence the excitatory impact on neuron N1 is reduced.
- **Postsynaptic inhibition**: A neurotransmitter acts directly on  neuron N1's receptors, leading to hyperpolarization of the membrane potential and hence a reduced probability of firing.

**My questions:**

(1) When we speak of "inhibitory post-synaptic potentials" (IPSPs), is this hence
always in the context of post-synaptic inhibition?

(2) I often read of "interneurons" (and it seems that this concept is used typically to refer to inhibitory neurons). Is inhibition by interneurons also always post-synaptic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Post-synaptic vs pre-synaptic inhibition**

Yes, inhibitory post-synaptic potentials (IPSPs) are always in the context of post-synaptic inhibition, because they are post-synaptic potentials. They occur because of inhibitory neurotransmitters (for example, GABA) are released and bind to post-synaptic receptors, particularly ligand-gated chloride channels. We often just call this "synaptic inhibition."

Pre-synaptic inhibition, on the other hand, would reduce the frequency/amplitude of *excitatory* post-synaptic potentials, by reducing neurotransmitter release at excitatory synapses (for example, glutamatergic synapses). You can also have pre-synaptic inhibition at an inhibitory synapse, where the pre-synaptic inhibition is actually disinhibitory from the perspective of the post-synaptic cell (inhibiting inhibition).

*In summary: post-synaptic inhibition is reducing the rate or probability of action potentials; pre-synaptic inhibition is affecting the quantity or probability of vesicle release.*

**Interneurons vs inhibitory cells**

Inhibitory interneurons are a major class of interneuron in the neocortex, but not all interneurons are inhibitory (layer 4 spiny stellate cells, for example, are excitatory interneurons). In addition, not all inhibitory cells are interneurons; some brain regions have inhibitory projection neurons, for example the cerebellum ([Purkinje cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purkinje_cell)) or striatum ([medium spiny neurons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_spiny_neuron)).

Inhibitory cells are those that release inhibitory neurotransmitters, so they are best thought of as involving post-synaptic inhibition. [Chandalier cells](https://doi.org/10.1016/0006-8993(85)90397-X) in cortex are a bit of a special case, because they synapse onto *axons* and interfere with action potentials that way, but I would not lump them in with presynaptic inhibitory mechanisms.

**Sources of pre-synaptic inhibition**

In general (because there may be exceptions, and almost certainly are in invertebrates who have very "weird" nervous systems from my mammal-biased worldview), presynaptic inhibition arises from three places: autoreceptors (self receptors), retrograde signalling from post-synaptic cells, and neuromodulation. One could fill textbooks with information on all the mechanisms, but I'll give one example of each of the three types:

**Autoreceptors**

Glutamatergic synapses, for example, can have pre-synaptic inhibitory [metabotropic glutamate receptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabotropic_glutamate_receptor). These are G-protein coupled receptors, not ion channels, and they typically respond when a synapse is very active. They are effectively a brake on over-activity: if a cell is firing too much, the effect of its firing will be decreased by pre-synaptic inhibition mediated by these self-receptors. This principle is common for other neurotransmitters, too. (Wu & Saggau, 1997)

**Presynaptic inhibition by post-synaptic cells**

Although we think of neuronal signalling as one way, that's not entirely true. Post-synaptic cells have mechanisms to communicate with the pre-synaptic cell, and this can include inhibiting that cell.

[Endocannabinoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endocannabinoid_system) are one mechanism: they are released by the post-synaptic cell and can reduce pre-synaptic release probability (Maejima et al 2001; Melis et al 2004). At an excitatory synapse, that makes them inhibitory; at an inhibitory synapse, they would be disinhibitory.

**Pre-synaptic inhibition by neuromodulators**

Pre-synaptic cells can also be affected by local concentrations of neuromodulators, like dopamine (Bamford et al 2004). Dopamine isn't necessarily released directly onto a cell but more into the surrounding area. Dopamine D2A receptors, for example, are found presynaptically at cortico-striatal synapses. Release of dopamine in the striatum reduces glutamate release at those synapses coming from cortex.

---

Bamford, N. S., Robinson, S., Palmiter, R. D., Joyce, J. A., Moore, C., & Meshul, C. K. (2004). Dopamine modulates release from corticostriatal terminals. Journal of Neuroscience, 24(43), 9541-9552.

Maejima, T., Hashimoto, K., Yoshida, T., Aiba, A., & Kano, M. (2001). Presynaptic inhibition caused by retrograde signal from metabotropic glutamate to cannabinoid receptors. Neuron, 31(3), 463-475.

Melis, M., Pistis, M., Perra, S., Muntoni, A. L., Pillolla, G., & Gessa, G. L. (2004). Endocannabinoids mediate presynaptic inhibition of glutamatergic transmission in rat ventral tegmental area dopamine neurons through activation of CB1 receptors. Journal of Neuroscience, 24(1), 53-62.

Nadim, F., & Bucher, D. (2014). Neuromodulation of neurons and synapses. Current opinion in neurobiology, 29, 48-56.

Wu, L. G., & Saggau, P. (1997). Presynaptic inhibition of elicited neurotransmitter release. Trends in neurosciences, 20(5), 204-212.

Comment: That was such a great answer that I took my time to read through all references. Thanks! I have a last question: Isn't a simpler presynaptic inhibitory mechanism just having the following chain of neurons: (inh neuron) --> (excitatory presynaptic neuron) --> (postsynaptic neuron). In this manner, the postsynaptic neuron is stimulated less when its presynaptic excitatory neuron is inhibited, and the presynaptic inhibition is a network effect?

Comment: @Pugl That would just be post-synaptic inhibition of the cell in the middle. It's presynaptic to the final cell that you are calling "postsynaptic", but it's post-synaptic to your inhibitory neuron. Probably the best way to distinguish would be to say that post-synaptic inhibition is referring to cases where you reduce the firing rate/firing probability of a cell; pre-synaptic inhibition is when you influence synaptic release to change the *effect* of a cell firing, without changing the firing rate/firing probability of the (pre-synaptic) cell.

Comment: Stated another way, post-synaptic inhibition is affecting action potentials; pre-synaptic inhibition is affecting vesicle release.

Comment: Exactly, I meant presynaptic to the final cell, thx! And that's a great and very concise definition you gave.

Comment: @Pugl I'll add it to my answer.